# Method "rel_length" in Neo4j.rb doesn't work.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, social-networking, neo4j.rb

I need to get "friends of friends" of `User`. So, `friend(rel_length: 2)` doesn't work (ignores method), returning friends.

```
class User
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  ...
  has_many :out, :friend, rel_class: Friend
  ...
end

class Friend
  include Neo4j::ActiveRel
  from_class User
  to_class User
  type 'friend'

  property :activity, type: String
  property :relation, type: String
  property :token, type: String
end
```

Comment: Please improve the question title.

Comment: Can you share the Cypher which is being generated when you try to call `friend(rel_length: 2)`?  You might need to add a `to_a` at the end or otherwise enumerate on it

Comment: fr=user.friend(rel_length:2)
Result is:
"<AssociationProxy @query_proxy=<QueryProxy [36mUser#friend[0m CYPHER: [33m"MATCH user0 WHERE (ID(user0) = {ID_user0}) MATCH user0-[rel1:`friend`]->({:rel_length=>2}:`User`)"[0m>>..."

fr=user.friend(rel_length:2).to_a
Result is:
"Invalid argument for RETURN. Full arguments: {:rel_length=>2} | Invalid part: 2"

Comment: What version of the `neo4j` and `neo4j-core` gems are you using?  `rel_length` was introduced in version 5.1.0, I believe

Comment: Indeed, the problem was in the version of gems. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to hear that fixed it!  If you ever want semi-real-time help we also hang out on Gitter: https://gitter.im/neo4jrb/neo4j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody finding this later the reason was because he was using an older version of the gem (see the comments)